# Is it legal to ride a bicycle with a self-installed motor around California?

Tags: united-states, california, traffic, driving, vehicle

I'm going to California for a few weeks, largely the San Francisco and Los Angeles areas, and to save money (and time considering LA traffic) I plan to bring a bicycle with me and use that and public transport to get around.

Seeing as a lot of the rides are long and hilly, and I have a good deal of electronics experience, I'm strongly considering mounting a motor to the bicycle to make my commute a bit easier. **Would a bicycle with a motor manually attached be street legal in California, specifically in Los Angeles and San Francisco?**

Comment: What is the wattage of the motor?  Does it stop assisting above a specific forward velocity?  Does the bike still have functional pedals that propel the bike ?    You may be better simply using the bike's gears and ride a bit slower up the hills.

Answer (score 1):

There are state laws pertaining to the operation of motorized bicycles (Vehicle code 21207.5.

> no motorized bicycle may be operated on a bicycle path or trail,
>   bikeway, bicycle lane established pursuant to Section 21207,
>   equestrian trail, or hiking or recreational trail, unless it is within
>   or adjacent to a roadway or unless the local authority or the
>   governing body of a public agency having jurisdiction over such path
>   or trail permits, by ordinance, such operation

However, [section 405](http://www.leginfo.ca.gov/cgi-bin/displaycode?section=veh&group=00001-01000&file=100-680) of the vehicle code distinguishes motorized bicycles and motor-driven cycles. Per 405:

> A "motor-driven cycle" is any motorcycle with a motor that displaces
>   less than 150 cubic centimeters. A motor-driven cycle does not include
>   a motorized bicycle, as defined in Section 406.

It does not matter if you do it yourself.

Comment: But is it street legal?